# Given polynomials $P$ and $Q$ of degree less than equal to $n,$ is $\|PQ\|\leq K \|P\| \cdot \|Q\|?$

Tags: real-analysis

Given polynomials $P$ and $Q$ of degree less than equal to $n,$ is $\|PQ\|\leq K \|P\| \cdot \|Q\|?$ Note that here the norm is the infinite norm and therefore $$\|P\| =\sup_{1\leq k\leq n}a_k$$
where $P=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_{i}x^{i}.$

I am guessing that $\|PQ\|\leq (n+1)(2n+1)\|P\|\cdot \|Q\|$, because each term can be controlled by $\|P\| \cdot \|Q\|.$ However I am not sure whether this is true. Perhaps someone could give a hint.

Comment: Do you mean $\|P\| = \max_{0 \le i \le n} |a_i|$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $P=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_{i}x^{i}, Q=\sum_{i=0}^{n}b_{i}x^{i}$

$PQ=\sum_{i=0}^{2n}(\sum_{j=\max\{0, i-n\}}^{\min\{i, n\}}a_{j}\cdot b_{i-j})x^{i}=\sum_{i=0}^{2n}c_{i}x^{i}$

$\|PQ\| =\sup_{0\leq k\leq 2n}|c_k|=\max_{0\leq k\leq 2n}|\sum_{j=\max\{0, k-n\}}^{\min\{k, n\}}a_{j}\cdot b_{k-j}|\\\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \leq(n+1)\max_{0\leq i\leq n}|a_i|\cdot \max_{0\leq j\leq n}|b_j|\\\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ =(n+1)\|P\|\cdot\|Q\|$

The $(n+1)$ factor arises because the coefficient of $x^{n}$ in $PQ$ contains $n+1$ addends of the form $(a_i\cdot b_j)$, which is the maximum number of addends of this form for any $c_k$. It can be easily seen that the number of such addends increases progressively from $1$ to $n+1$ while calculating $c_0$ through $c_n$, and then decreases progressively to $1$. In other words, the "lengthiest" coefficent is $c_n$.